# Unknown sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver's Instance

Tags: tomcat, jdbc

I de-register JDBC drivers in a ContextListener's contextDestroyed method (Tomcat), and I notice two JDBC drivers instead of one.

I do indeed load an instance of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`, but I have no idea why nor who loads `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JDBC 4 (Java 6) JDBC drivers are loaded automatically when on the classpath with the right services entry.

The JdbcOdbcDriver is loaded automatically in Java 6 and 7, because it is on the classpath (it is part of Java itself); it was removed in Java 8.

Note that you don't need to remove this driver, as it was loaded for the entire JVM, and not just for your context (the web application).

Comment: I will simply de-register it on contextInitialized() then.

Comment: @MohamedEnnahdiElIdrissi If you don't use it that is not really a problem, however if you have other applications running in the same tomcat, and you do this, then those applications won't have access to this driver either. It was loaded by the system classloader and not by the context classloader.